# ¿Cómo realizar una consulta dentro de una entidad en Symfony 3?

Tags: php, symfony3, orm

A la hora de insertar datos en una de las tablas de mi base de datos en mi proyecto de Symfony, necesito ver si son válidos y para eso dentro de la entidad, creé un función para validar la inserción.

Necesito ver los datos que se insertaron con anterioridad para compararlos pero no sé cómo realizar consultas dentro de la entidad. No sé cómo llamar al entity manger desde la entidad.

Comment: No creo que hacer una consulta dentro de la entidad sea el enfoque más adecuado. Cuál es exactamente la validación que deseas realizarle a tu entidad ???

Comment: es un sitio para solicitar locales. Cuando se realiza una solicitud (una entrada a la tabla solicitud) necesito ver que la que se esta añadiendo, no coincide con las ya insertadas en cuanto a hora de inicio y hora fin, local y dia. si coincide en esas cosas no se puede realizar la solicitud.

Comment: Entonces es parte de la lógica de tu aplicación, compruébalo desde un Action a través de una DQL o pon todo el código DQL en el Repository de la Entidad involucrada si consideras que lo usarás en otros Actions.

Answer (score 1):

Otra cosa, está la validación de tipo `@UniqueConstraint`, esta se aplica en la definición de la entidad y se le establecen las columnas que formarán parte del índice. Eso sí, tendrá efecto a nivel de esquema, no podrá validarse a nivel de formulario por tanto deberás hacer el tratamiento de errores pertinente a la hora de persistir la entidad para capturar la excepción.
Ejemplo:

```
@ORM\Table(name="solicitud",uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(name='solicitudUnica_idx', columns={'hora_inicio', 'hora_fin', 'otra_columna'}))
class Solicitud{

    @ORM\Column(type="datetime") 
    private $hora_inicio;

    @ORM\Column(type="datetime") 
    private $hora_fin;

    @ORM\Column(type="int") 
    private $otra_columna;

}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias no me había dado cuenta de esta idea. Excelente ayuda. Estaba tan enfrascado en la otra idea que no me había percatado de esto. Muchísimas gracias sinceramente.